# VS Code JSX auto-formatter

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

Is there a VS code extension that will auto format codes like this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of formatters out there. You could use [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) ([VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)) to achieve that out of the box.

Be aware that Prettier is very opinitionated. If you'd prefer a more configurable formatter check out [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) that can also be used as a formatter with the [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)